# auto-apply permissions to any *.sh script

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I'm wondering if there is some magical mechanism that will allow me to apply UMASK settings to specific file *types*.

It took many years but I'm finally irritated with running a `chmod u+x script.sh` on - every - single - script I write. So, the question is...

How would one automatically apply the above permissions to any file with a .sh extension?

If it matters, I'm on a **macOS** laptop with the latest bash/zsh binaries; the default shell is zsh.

Comment: If you use `vim` - look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39982/vim-create-file-with-x-bit/39995#39995). And don't tag `MacOS` questions as Linux. :P

Comment: Frame challenge: Executables shouldn't have extensions at all in the first place. When you add a shebang to a script and mark it +x, it shouldn't have an extension any more than `ls` or `cp` does. (Similarly, you run `pip`, not `pip.py`, even though it's written in Python).

Comment: There's an essay on the topic that's been linked for many years by the bash IRC channel's factoid bot at [Commandname extensions considered harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/)

Comment: (Shell **libraries** should have extensions, just as Python libraries, JavaScript libraries, Ruby libraries, etc do; but executables start their own interpreter, so they don't need an extension to indicate which interpreters they're compatible with).

Comment: Couldn't you just run the file with eg `bash script.sh`?

Comment: One bizarre, but possible, solution would be to write a zsh `precmd`, which is executed before the command itself is run. This precmd could check the command name, use `file` on it to make a guess of whether it is a shell script, and if it is, it could change the permissions. Not that I would **recommend** doing it, but I find your hole idea horrible.

Comment: Yep, I've been a part of the Bash IRC channel since the 90s - I get it. Also, I don't like it either but the annoyance is real. And, annoyances are part of what we automate away. @tink, I like the vim suggestion, thank you.

Comment: I don't recommend this, but you could run a cron job something like `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do head -n 1 "$f" | grep -qE  "^#!/bin/(ba|[kz))?sh" && chmod u+x "$f"; done' _ {} +`

Comment: `newzsh(){ print '#!/usr/bin/env zsh' >${1:?}; chmod u+x $1 }`

Comment: @todd_dsm - glad you do ... let us know how that worked for you! =)

Comment: or https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html if you place them in the same dir (i.e. ~/bin).